# How to use rollbacks with Spring AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests

Tags: java, spring

Im missing something in my understanding about how rollbacks are done in Spring when doing integrationstest.

What im having problem with is that the following code works. Before the test is run the relevant data gets inserted making the test pass. After the test is done running the test data is no longer in the database. Everything works fine.

```
@ContextConfiguration( { Configs.TEST })
public class EndpointDaoBeanIT extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    // Since I have two datasources I need to explicitly state wich to use.
    @Override
    @Resource(name = "ds1")
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) { 
      this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource); 
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyDao myDao;

@Before
public void init() {
    final String insertSql =
          "INSERT INTO T1 (" +
          " ID) " +
          "VALUES (?)";

    // define query arguments
    Object[] params = new Object[] { "iddd" };

    // define SQL types of the arguments
    int[] types = new int[] { Types.VARCHAR };

    jdbcTemplate.update(insertSql, params, types);
}

@Test
public void testGetId() {
    SomeType t1 = myDao.getbyId("iddd");
    assertThat(t1.get(), equalTo("iddd"));
}
}
```

However in the following test both the data in the `@Before` and the data from `testAddData()` gets saved in the database. Causing the test to pass the first time it runs and fail every time after (because of buplicate ids). Not sure what im doing wrong but I guess it has soemthing todo with that im using two different connections somehow?

```
@Test
public void testAddData() {
    final String DATA_ID = "TestID2";

    // Add data to database
    myDao.addData(DATA_ID);

    // Retrive added data
    String testData = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
            "SELECT SOME FROM TABLE WHERE DATA =?",
            String.class, DATA_ID);

   // Assert that it is the same data
   assertThat(testData, equalTo(DATA_ID));
}
```

This is the relavant parts of my configuration file:

```
<bean id ="myDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
...
</bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="myJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="myDataSource" />
</bean>
```

My my question is, the the example abowe, what is it that causes the data in the secound test to be presistet and not roll back?

How would I rewrite the test to work in the expected manner?

Comment: Don't you have to annotate the test with `@Transactional` and `@Rollback(true)` or `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)`?

Comment: It is my understanding that when i extend AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests this is already done in the super class?

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems like `AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests` is annotated with `@Transactional`, but not with any rollback information.

Comment: defaultRollback = true is the default value I think, I shold not have to annotate my tests with rollback info...

Comment: [Hmm, yeah you're right.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-tx-rollback-and-commit-behavior)